# Spark Dataframe to Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am trying to stream the Spark Dataframe to Kafka consumer. I am unable to do , Can you please advice me.

I am able to pick the data from Kafka producer to Spark , and I have performed some manipulation, After manipulating the data , I am interested to stream it back to Kafka (Consumer).

Comment: "Not able to do", what exactly problem are you facing? if possible minimum workable code should be included as a part of question.

Comment: val ds = df1.writeStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("topic", "kafka_topic_13").start()  DF1 is a Spark dataframe , I want this data frame to be streamed to kafka. Getting error saying that the dataframe (df1) is not a streaming data frame/dataset.

Comment: You need to loop over each partition of the dataframe. For each partition, you then loop over all elements and send them through a Kafka Producer. I don't have code, but I'm sure you're not the first to ask this

Comment: yeah I m writing inside the loop, as i am not having enough space here i could not show the entire code :( , I am trying other way around, working on it..

Comment: @GuruprasadSwaminathan You can always edit the question and provide all the information required.

Answer (score 12):

Here is an example of producing to kafka in streaming, but the batch version is almost identical

streaming from a source to kafka:

```
 val ds = df
      .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
      .writeStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
      .option("topic", "topic1")
      .start()
```

writing a static dataframe (not streamed from a source) to kafka

```
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .write
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("topic", "topic1")
  .save()
```

please keep in mind that

1. each row will be a message.
2. the dataframe must be a streaming dataframe. If you have a static dataframe then use the static version.

take a look at the basic documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

it sounds like you have a static dataframe, that isn't streaming from a source.

Comment: Thank you very much:)
It is working now, after upgrading to 2.3.0 from 2.1.1.

Comment: I upgraded the system
Also I updated my build.sbt to point out to 2.3.0 .